# Why is Hazelcast so slow for basic operations like get and put?

Tags: hazelcast

I have a two box cluster running Hazelcast 3.6.

I am trying to run some very basic tests to get a feel for performance. Gets, puts and an aggregation across a map of Integers are all seriously slow.

I am seeing about 2.6 get or put operations per second. Any idea why this might be?

This is my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("10.90.288.14", "10.90.288.15");

    HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

    IMap<Integer, Integer> map = client.getMap("int-map");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        map.put(i, i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        map.get(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Summed:" + map.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());

    client.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

Comment: 2.6 like literally 2.6/sec? How do you measure that, can't see it from the above code.

Comment: In Hazelcast management centre.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would fix is to remove the System.outs on every get since this has a significant overhead. If you really want to log something, add something like this:

`if(k%1000==0)println("whatever")`

Also you need a lot longer running time to say anything sensible, with 1k runs, you have not even heated up the JIT. So run at least 1M time.

And I would calculate the performance directly by storing the time before you start, and storing the time after the test. And you get something like

`long duration=endMs-startMs;
double throughput = (1000d*iteration)/duration`

Comment: I have run with 1,000,000 and without the println. My measurements are taken from management centre. I think it might be network latency ...

Comment: What kind of network do you use? That sounds like a horrible one ;)

Comment: Use the approach I have given above to determine a basic throughput.